# Grouping dataframe by similar non matching values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

If I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns: **id**, **num**, **amount**.

I want to group the dataframe such that all rows in each group have the same **id** and **amount** and where each row's value of **num** has a value that is not more than 10 larger or smaller the next row's value of **num**.

For the same **id**, if one row to the next does not have the same **amount** or if the absolute difference between the two **num** values is more than 10 then it will start a new grouping. Having a row with a different **id** in the middle does not break a grouping.

How can I go about doing this?

I have not managed to make a grouping where I'm not looking for matching values (like here where I need it to be close - but not matching). I'm assuming that this would need some custom grouping function but I've been having trouble putting one together

**Example dataframe:**

| id | amount | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa-aaa | 130 | 12 |
| aaa-aaa | 130 | 39 |
| bbb-bbb | 270 | 41 |
| ccc-ccc | 130 | 19 |
| bbb-bbb | 270 | 37 |
| aaa-aaa | 130 | 42 |
| aaa-aaa | 380 | 39 |

**Expected Groups:**

Group 1:

| id | amount | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa-aaa | 130 | 12 |

Group 2:

| id | amount | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa-aaa | 130 | 39 |
| aaa-aaa | 130 | 42 |

Group 3:

| id | amount | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bbb-bbb | 270 | 41 |
| bbb-bbb | 270 | 37 |

Group 4:

| id | amount | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ccc-ccc | 130 | 19 |

Group 5:

| id | amount | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa-aaa | 380 | 39 |

Comment: What would happen if the num for bbb-bbb was 29 rather than 39?

Comment: @mozway Sorry, did not know new rules :S

Comment: @yem the logic is unclear, if you add an additional row with 29, should it merge the 2 groups? Also you mention grouping by ID but they are all different in your example

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I edited the question and the example dataframe. Hopefully I made it more clear now. Let me know if the intended logic is still unclear.

Comment: I guess my question was, if you have `[10, 15, 20, 26, 30]` with the same ID, should they be grouped together as the difference is never more than 10? But if you remove the 20 then you would have 2 groups

Comment: @mozway I'm not sure I understood. If you remove the 10 wouldn't it be `[15, 20, 26, 30]` which would still have a difference less than 10 from one to the next?

Comment: Sorry typo, I meant remove 20

Comment: Correct. If you remove the 20 then I would want it to be 2 groupings.

Comment: OK, then my approach should work like you want. Just remove the sorting if you want only want to consider the threshold in the original order (`[10, 5, 16]` would be 2 groups), else keep it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear, but assuming you want to start a new group when there is a gap of more than 10:

```
close = (df.sort_values(by=['amount', 'num'])
           .groupby('amount')
           ['num'].diff().abs().gt(10).cumsum()
         )

for _, g in df.groupby(['amount', close]):
    print(g, end='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
        id  amount  num
0  aaa-aaa     130   12
3  ddd-ddd     130   19

        id  amount  num
1  bbb-bbb     130   39

        id  amount  num
2  ccc-ccc     270   41
4  eee-eee     270   37
```

###### how it works:

```
# sort values by amount/sum
df.sort_values(by=['amount', 'num'])

        id  amount  num
0  aaa-aaa     130   12
3  ccc-ccc     130   19
1  aaa-aaa     130   39
5  aaa-aaa     130   42
4  bbb-bbb     270   37
2  bbb-bbb     270   41
6  aaa-aaa     380   39

# get the absolute successive difference in "num"
(df.sort_values(by=['amount', 'num'])
   .groupby('amount')
   ['num'].diff().abs()
)

0     NaN
3     7.0
1    20.0
5     3.0
4     NaN
2     4.0
6     NaN
Name: num, dtype: float64

# check if it's greater than 10 and cumsum
# to create a grouper for groupby

[...].gt(10).cumsum()

0    0
3    0
1    1
5    1
4    1
2    1
6    1
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @GoldenLion sure, I added details

Answer (score 1):

With sorting by `amount` and `num` and adding an auxiliary marker column as [difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) (that fits a threshold) between consecutive values:

```
groups = df.sort_values(['amount', 'num'])\
         .assign(diff_=lambda x: x['num'].diff().abs().fillna(0).le(10))\
         .groupby(['amount', 'diff_'])
for _, g in groups:
    print(g)
```

---

```
         id  amount  num  diff_
1  bbb-bbb      130   39  False
         id  amount  num  diff_
0  aaa-aaa      130   12   True
3  ddd-ddd      130   19   True
         id  amount  num  diff_
4  eee-eee      270   37   True
2  ccc-ccc      270   41   True
```

Comment: That's not going to work. If you have `[1, 2, 15, 16, 38, 99]`, with your logic this is going to group `[1, 2, 16]` and `[15, 38, 99]`. You need to use a `cumsum` to group the successive rows after passing a threshold (see my answer).

Comment: ps. I realize I forgot to use the absolute difference myself ;)

Comment: @mozway, well, I've tried `[1, 2, 15, 16, 38]` and it shows that you were wrong, it emits 4 different groups. By the way, it sounds strange when you say that some approach is definitely wrong and "*The logic is not fully clear*"  at same time

Comment: [Are you sure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyr5l.png)? On which data did you test? (Btw, my remark was only friendly)

Comment: @mozway, the OP's data and `num` values from your comment (as `'num': dict(enumerate([1, 2, 15, 16, 38]))`)

Comment: Here is a reproducible example: `df = pd.DataFrame({'amount': [130, 130, 270, 130, 270, 130, 130, 130], 'num': [1, 2, 41, 15, 37, 16, 38, 99]})`, see for yourself 1/2/16 are grouped, so are 15/38/99